# Como eu faço para Mudar o conteúdo da tela usando php

Tags: php

Tenho um sistema que ele possui duas possibilidades de uso para o usuário:

1.manual

2.automatica

queria que o usuário pudesse escolher entre essas duas versões no estilo `input type='radio'`. Assim só atualizando a página com o conteúdo que o cliente escolheu (manual ou automático)

```
<body id="body">
    <div id="DivTopo">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <?php
                    include "TopoLogado.php";
                    ?>
                </div>
                <div> 
     <form action="Atividade.php">
    <INPUT TYPE="RADIO" NAME="OPCAO" VALUE="1">Kanban Automático
    <INPUT TYPE="RADIO" NAME="OPCAO" VALUE="2">Kanban Manual
    <input type="submit" value="atualizar">
    </form> 

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div id="DivCentral"><br>
        <h1 class="Titulo">Tarefas de <?php echo $tblDetalhes['nome_ATIVIDADE'] ?></h1>

        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">


                    <?php 
                    if($_POST["OPCAO"]==1 ){

                    include 'KANBAN1.php';

                    } else if ($_POST["OPCAO"]==2){
                         include 'KANBAN2.php';
                    }
                    ?>

                    <div id="DivRodape">
                        <?php include "Rodape.php"; ?>  
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  <script>
 <?php
 include "./JavaScript/Modal.js";
 ?>
    </script>
</body>
```

Pensei em fazer dessa forma também:

```
<div class="pre-spoiler">

<input id="xs" value="Leia Mais" style="margin-left: 50px; padding: 0px; width: 80px; " onclick="if (this.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('div')[1].getElementsByTagName('div')[0].style.display != '') { this.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('div')[1].getElementsByTagName('div')[0].style.display = '';this.innerText = ''; this.value = 'Ocultar'; } else { this.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('div')[1].getElementsByTagName('div')[0].style.display = 'none'; this.value = 'Leia Mais';}" type="button"> </div>

<div>

<div class="spoiler" style="display: none;">

<?php include 'KANBAN1' ?>

</div>

</div>
```

Mas a primeira funciona, mas a segunda não (aparece o mesmo conteudo da primeira)

Comment: Por favor, poste o código que você possui para complementar sua pergunta. Dessa forma fica mais fácil pra comunidade poder ajudar.

Comment: @PauloImon pronto

Comment: Não seria só configurar o seu `<form>` pra enviar os valores por `POST` para essa mesma página? Já está até fazendo a condição com os valores recebidos. Não entendi qual a sua dificuldade.

Comment: não está funcionando

Comment: Coloque: `<form action="" method="post">` e teste.

Comment: @PauloImon opa, é isso mesmo +1 pro seu comentário.

Comment: Que bom! Precisando estamos aí. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se entendi o que você quer é que quando depois da pessoa escolher uma opção essa opção ficasse salva, é isto?

E também tem o que o @Paulo disse, troque o form por:

```
 <form action="" method="post">
```

O `action=""` vai atualizar a página atual, assim não precisará informar a URL

Se for o caso então você pode usar cookies, deve ficar assim o seu código:

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST["OPCAO"])) {
     if ($_POST["OPCAO"] == 1 || $_POST["OPCAO"] == 2) {
        //Atualiza o valor quando o usuário solicitar (o cookie expira em um ano)
        setcookie('temakaban', $_POST["OPCAO"], time() + 31536000, '/');
        $_COOKIE['temakaban'] = $_POST["OPCAO"];
     }
}
?>
<html>

....

<body id="body">
    <div id="DivTopo">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <?php
                    include "TopoLogado.php";
                    ?>
                </div>
                <div> 
    <form action="" method="post">
    <INPUT TYPE="RADIO" NAME="OPCAO" VALUE="1">Kanban Automático
    <INPUT TYPE="RADIO" NAME="OPCAO" VALUE="2">Kanban Manual
    <input type="submit" value="atualizar">
    </form> 

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div id="DivCentral"><br>
        <h1 class="Titulo">Tarefas de <?php echo $tblDetalhes['nome_ATIVIDADE'] ?></h1>

        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">

                    <?php
                    //Por padrão usará KANBAN1, acaso o usuário não tenha escolhido
                    if(empty($_COOKIE["temakaban"]) || $_COOKIE["temakaban"] == 1){
                         include 'KANBAN1.php';
                    } else if ($_COOKIE["temakaban"]==2){
                         include 'KANBAN2.php';
                    }
                    ?>

                    <div id="DivRodape">
                        <?php include "Rodape.php"; ?>  
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  <script>
 <?php
 include "./JavaScript/Modal.js";
 ?>
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: obrigadaa ^---^

Comment: por algum motivo mesmo eu selecionando a opção 2, volta para a 1

Comment: @J.Jones opa, vou testar e já te aviso

Comment: editei a pergunta

Comment: @J.Jones atualizei a resposta, troquei session por cookie, porque a sessão  é destruída quando fecha o navegador, dessa forma deve funcionar melhor, tinha um erro na if também, já corrigi.

Comment: em vez de echo não deveria ser include?

Comment: @J.Jones tanto dentro de um include quanto fora o funcionamento será o mesmo, o código é só um exemplo de uso pra explicar como funciona, você pode adaptar como desejar.

Comment: é que dá esse erro quando eu coloco o include no lugar do echo : Warning: include(KANBAN2.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in

Comment: aparece nas duas páginas, tanto na dois quanto na um

Comment: não precisa se desculpar

Comment: @J.Jones  corrigi o código. O KANBAN2.php e o KANBAN1.php estão na mesma pasta?

Comment: sim, estão na mesma pasta

Comment: você esta usando esses includes em outras páginas? O erro `Warning: include(KANBAN2.php)` continua?

Comment: Funcionouu, muito obrigadaaa